# How to export from Illustrator to Photoshop ensuring quality as much as possible?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So i have this picture [image]

, and I want to export it to Photoshop such that it is as close as possible to the original vector in illustrator. However, I get this when exporting to psd with write layers, with the picture being not smooth enough for further development? So how do I get this done? [image]

Comment: Illustrator will rasterize the paths when exporting as a Photoshop file. What are you trying to do in Photoshop with the Illustrator file?

Comment: I am trying to make some additional effects to the image in photoshop, so I need to preserve quality, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: You can click and drag an AI file directly into Photoshop.  No need to convert it.  It will automatically become a Smart Object, which will still be editable in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

### One answer is: You do not

Ok, This probably will not solve your problem, let's go a bit deeper.

In general terms, the idea is to prepare an asset that you need in Raster format and then assemble them in a Vector program.

If your image is already in vectors and it is ok as it is, it "should" remain in vectors.

But this is probably not your case, where you (probably) want to retouch your image and add some effects.

### Ok, you need to

Let us analyze first: Do I?

Can you add the effects you need in the Vector program? Can you duplicate your object to have vector elements **and** raster effects?

### YES I need to!

Ok, ok... then simply export to the proper resolution... >:o) (evil face here) Muahaha, this is the tricky part!

What is the real proper resolution you need?

In general terms, for print you export at the real size at 300PPI, yes the image could start viewing some unwanted blurriness but as this is really a necessary step it is probably good feedback that the design will NOT work as you intended.

In the case of your image, you need to define if you want the horizontal lines to be razor-sharp or not.

On a commercial print when you rasterize them they will be screened at an 45° angle so they **will** be blurry, (that is why you need to leave them as vectors)

For screen, you need to define the real spacing of them. You probably want them razor-sharp on screen, then you need to decide if they will be exactly for example 3 pixels width and 3 pixels spacing.

If you simply choose a random size to work with and a random export setting some lines will be aliased, some will have a gray line of pixels, some will have more space than others. Then try to work in the vector program with some pixel-perfect preview and snap.

These are two examples of why this is a tricky part of designing assets.

### One last resource

Is simply to export at a much higher resolution than you probably (or probably will not) need, let's say at 300%, retouch happily your image, play with effects in Ps, and do not worry about the output until that day comes, and live happily with the result even if it is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the Illustrator file in Photoshop

First, make sure your file is saved with PDF compatibility turned on.
[image: The PDF compatibility option is in the options panel when you save-as an AI file]

Then open the AI file in Photoshop. This can be done either through the open menu, or just by dragging the AI file onto the photoshop application icon. You'll be asked what you want to do with the file. Select the artboard you want on the left, set the dimensions as you want, and then choose your import settings. I recommend using the following settings:

- Crop To: Art Box (unless you've sized your artboards to fit your art, in which case select Media Box)
- check Anti-aliased
- 300 DPI
- choose RGB or CMYK depending on the color mode you have set in your Illustrator document

Presto! You now have a flat raster to which you can apply effects

A less straightforward approach would be importing the AI file as a smart-object into a photoshop layer, but that's finnicky and results in a larger PSD file.